# 30,000 rhinos were to attack South America, will they survive?

Tags: warfare, invasion

Say that 30,000 rhinos are going to attack South America. If they all team up in Cape Town, what will be the most likely route?

What is the chances for the rhinos to succeed? How many of the rhinos are likely to die in the process, if the fact was true that a rhino can withstand 800 fifty caliber gunshots.

The rhinos here are very intelegent, so they'll use the shortest way to South America. They will divide the rhinos in two groups, one is the attacker and one is backup.

Now the rhinos will take the shortest route to a place in South America.
They like popular cities with lots of food, so they can quench their hunger, aggressively.

I want a long answer, possible even a story long answer, cause this will require a long answer to answer. I need every detail of your answers to answer this question. If you requested that I will share my opinion, I will as fast as I can.

Now, come for the attack, you know what? The soldiers will have 10x magnification binoculars, which means 257 km will look like 25.7 km in the binoculars right? A binocular can usually see 25 km at 2 meters high, so... The binoculars will detect the rhinos, but they aren't clearly seen until 125 km away(that's 12.5 km away in a binocular).

But that is too far for most guns to shoot. Most guns can fire at a maximum of 2,000 to 3,000 meters away, so here's the problem. By the time the rhinos are already this close, it'll be hard to keep the rhinos away from the barricades. By already this time, the rhinos are aiming at the heart of South America. Destroys the heart, South America is claimed back by the rhinos which is D:

But then the soldiers want to protect the heart of the continent, so now all the soldiers are packed at the core, but they won't stop killing the rhinos. If there is a chance the rhinos will ever make it, ALL the continents will take revenge against the rhinos. But they have to save at least 33% of the soldiers in the heart of the city, so in case the rhinos spread further, soldiers will attack the rhinos.

If you like, you can tell me about the possibility of the rhinos attacking all other continents, as this is even worse like this ;_;

Comment: "the rhinos are very intelligent".  OK, but that's not enough.  What level of technology do they have - especially military technology?  What's their culture?  Why are they interested in taking over South America?  What relationships do they have with human nations?  How much human money do they have?

Comment: I don't want to make an answer out of this, but they won't be able to do any damage at all.  Cape Town is in South **Africa**.  The Rhinos would need to board a ship to get to South America, and they're going to have a hard time buying passage on any vessel I know of without attracting quite a lot of attention!

Comment: You say you want a really long answer butbquestionscreqiiring a long answer are usually too broad and are discouraged on the site.

Comment: What makes you think a Rhino can take 800 .50 cal shots?  Have you not noticed they are going extinct because people are hunting them?

Comment: Which part of South America?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Chris. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to the development of fictional worlds, not the stories that occur in them. You seem to be asking us to develop the heart of your plot for you, which is definitely outside our [scope](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I would suggest taking the [tour] to get a better understanding of how the site works.

Comment: Their biggest problem is that poachers would descend on Cape Town and kill them off for their horns. Rhinos have had it tough but they shouldn't surrender the moral high ground.

Answer (score 6):

There is zero chance of success because the fleet of ships carrying the rhinos across the Atlantic would be picked up by naval radar [60 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_Radar)  to [400 km](https://translate.google.ca/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.invap.com.ar%2Fes%2Fla-empresa%2Fsala-de-prensa%2Fnovedades%2F1184-se-inauguro-un-radar-3d-de-largo-alcance-en-formosa.html&edit-text=&act=url) from shore and sunk when they fail to turn back.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume they swam without getting detected, amassed at the shore. As soon as military understands that there is something wrong, entire horde can be obliterated by repeated jet strikes or tanks. All they might do is some damage. I think you underestimate military capability of humans and overestimate the speed of rhinos (40km/h during full charge).

Comment: Rhinos are an endangered species, but this is taking it to a new level entirely.

Comment: I guess it might even be possible to save most of them.

Comment: If so, that would be a kindness to future generations.